# Stacking numpy arrays with unknown dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Im looking for a way to stack numpy arrays from a source that can have dynamic dimensions on the zero axes.

```
stack_arrays = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)

sources = ["source_1", "source_2"]

for source in sources:

  //return 3D array in the form of (N,W,H) where W and H are fixed but you dont know the size of W and H
  new_arrays = get_arrays(source)
  stack_arrays = np.append(stack_arrays , new_arrays , axis=0)
```

When I try to run this code I get an error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)
```

How can I make the np array to be able to take any kind of 2D shape and to stack it.

EDIT:

I managed to solve it by using reshape at the end.

```
    stack_arrays = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
    dim_w, dim_h, rows = 0, 0, 0

    sources = ["source_1", "source_2"]

    for source in sources:
          //return 3D array in the form of (N,W,H) where W and H are fixed but you dont know the size of W and H
      new_arrays = get_arrays(source)
      dim_w, dim_h = new_arrays.shape[1], new_arrays.shape[2]
      rows = rows + new_arrays.shape[0]
      stack_arrays = np.append(stack_arrays , new_arrays , axis=0)

new_arrays = new_arrays.reshape(rows, dim_w, dim_h)
```

Comment: You totally forgot to show us any of your data.  Please make a small example that actually runs (we don't know what `get_arrays()` does), with the same dimensions but fake data such as `np.zeros((4,2,3))` or whatever matches your actual data.  Also please tell us your desired output for some small example input.

Comment: get_arrays() return 3D array in the form of (N,W,H) where W and H are fixed but you dont know the size

Comment: You say "W and H are fixed but you dont know the size of W and H".  This doesn't really make sense.  "Fixed" usually means known in advance.  Again you have not provided even the smallest bit of example input or desired output.  You're unlikely to find help this way.

Comment: The the size of W and H are always the same for all the source but can change any day. For example today W and H are 100,200 but tomorrow is 300,500. The the dimensions of the array are dynamic and because of that I cannot declare my first numpy array size because I cant know in advance what W and H will be

Comment: Don't `np.append` in the loop.  `list` `append` instead.  Then `np.concatenate` the whole list at the end.  It's faster and easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.concatenate([getarray(source) for source in sources], axis=0)
```

is simpler and faster.